# Compilation error in maven tycho plugin

Tags: java, maven

```
 File logFile = Platform.getLogFileLocation().toFile();
 ^^^^
 File cannot be resolved to a type

 File logFile = Platform.getLogFileLocation().toFile();
 ^^^^^^^^
 Platform cannot be resolved
 2 problems (2 errors)
```

I am experiencing errors on building my project. As above, I am using the Platform class to get the log file eclipse is making.
So, my problem is maven cannot resolve org.eclipse.runtime jar.
I tried installing the jar in my local repo but it is still failing.

Any idea's guy?

- A total beginner.

Comment: Have you imported those classes ?

Comment: Did you import `java.io.File`?

Comment: It's my bad, :| Forgot to import the classes. Got used to eclipse doing it for me and forgot that I was only using Notepad++ at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getLogFileLocation().toFile()` returns an instance of `java.io.File` (standard JDK class). Make sure you import the class in your code.